# How can I add li "function" to an already existing class?

Tags: php, html, css, html-lists

apologies for my bad title explanation. I've got a code which I'm trying to restyle, part of which is below. The PHP document I'm using does a (JSON) query to get active "boxes" to show up on screen, and automatically orders them as a list. I want the queried boxes in 2 columns, it doesn't have to be an ordered list.

Problem is, there is no *li* class in my .php file so I'm thinking I'll have to edit one of the classes below to achieve this?

```
<div class="x-container max width agent-container" style="margin: 0px auto;padding: 0px;">'

 <div class="x-column x-sm x-2-3";>
```

Is there a way to "add" *li* to the CSS or is there another way around it?

I know I can use a code like

```
display: block;
width: 50%;
float: left;
```

to add to my *li* class.. but I'd still need a *li* class right? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="entry-content content homepage-agents">

  <?php while(have_posts()): the_post();?>

  <?php the_content();?>

  <?php endwhile;?>

  <div class="x-container max width agent-container" style="margin: 0px auto;padding: 0px;">

    <div class="x-column x-sm x-2-3";>

      <div class="agent-data">

        <?php

        /**
        * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
        */
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');

        if(is_plugin_active('consulenten-plugin-business/consulenten-plugin-business.php')): $jm_cplb = new ConsulentenpluginBusiness(); endif;

        if(is_plugin_active('consulenten-plugin-lite/consulenten-plugin-lite.php')): $jm_cplb = new ConsulentenpluginLite(); endif;                             

        $array_boxes = (array)$jm_cplb->jm_cplb_loadjson();
```

This is some css..

```
}

.agent-container {
    margin-top: 60px !important;
    margin-bottom: 60px !important;        
}

.agent-item {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: How is the HTML generated? Do you have access to the PHP file that generates the HTML? If that is possible i would suggest to add the class while generating, not to monkey patch some other class as that will have consequences in other places.

Comment: Agreed. I've only got this, I don't think I can get anything useful out of this, can I? Edited my original post for reference.. it's just part of the php file but the rest is useless..

Comment: Plus I've asked the original creator for more insight into the PHP file.. hope it'll help.